# Change pid_max on ec2

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, pid

I'm trying to set pid_max on an ec2 server but I keep getting Permission denied.

```
sudo echo 4194303 > /proc/sys/kernel/pid_max
```

Any ideas why?

```
[ec2-user@www ~]$ cat /proc/version 
Linux version 3.2.12-3.2.4.amzn1.i686 (mockbuild@gobi-build-31006) (gcc version 4.4.6 20110731 (Red Hat 4.4.6-3) (GCC) ) #1 SMP Thu Mar 22 07:59:03 UTC 2012
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`echo` is running as root, but you're still redirecting the output as your user.

You either need to use `tee`:

```
echo 4194303 | sudo tee /proc/sys/kernel/pid_max
```

Or run the whole command as root:

```
sudo sh -c "echo 4194303 > /proc/sys/kernel/pid_max"
```

Comment: Thanks @Blender but both command doesn't work. I copy pasted the command on the terminal and below are the result:
First command output: tee: /proc/sys/kernel/pid_max: Invalid argument
second command output: sh: line 0: echo: write error: Invalid argument

Comment: BTW, I tried to edit the file via vim but same error - Permission Denied.

Comment: @ian: Both work just fine for me. What distro are you running?

Comment: Amazon linux on Amazon EC2. Are you also trying it on an ec2 instance?

Comment: [ec2-user@www ~]$ cat /proc/version 

Linux version 3.2.12-3.2.4.amzn1.i686 (mockbuild@gobi-build-31006) (gcc version 4.4.6 20110731 (Red Hat 4.4.6-3) (GCC) ) #1 SMP Thu Mar 22 07:59:03 UTC 2012